# CSV format data input to mysql with separator

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, export-to-csv

I want import an input List in csv format, with separator (|), from an Textarea to my MySQL Database.

But it always failed, also if its in the correct format.

It comes the message: `Error, 0 added successfully.`

My format:

```
Thomas|Maier|5778011152|Bahnweg|232
```

Any one an Idea?

```
if(isset($_POST["base_name"]) && isset($_POST["new_entry"])) {
    $myList = preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", preg_split("/$\R?^/m", $_POST["new_entry"]));
    foreach($myList as $info) $csv[] = explode($_POST["separator"], $info);

    $csvParams = $csv[0];
    array_shift($csv);

    $success = 0;
    $total = 0;

    foreach($csv as $info) {
        $sqlInsert = array_combine($csvParams, $info);
        $sqlInsert["base"] = $_POST["base_name"];
        $sqlInsert["info"] = "unbenutzt";

        $p = softwareInsertArray($softwareSqlLink, $sqlInsert, "person");
        if($p) $success++;
        $total++;
    }

    $q = softwareRunQuery($softwareSqlLink, false, "INSERT INTO statistics (`key`, `val`) VALUES ('".$_POST["base_name"]."|profit', '0');");
}

if(isset($total)) {
    if($total == $success && $total > 0 && $q) {
        $alert = array("type" => "success", "header" => "Erfolgreich!", "text" => "Success.");
        softwareSqlLog($softwareSqlLink, "person", array("status" => 1, "info" => array("base" => $_POST["base_name"], "text" => $success." person added successfully")));
    } else {
        $alert = array("type" => "danger", "header" => "Fehler!", "text" => $success."/".$total." sucess.");
        softwareSqlLog($softwareSqlLink, "person", array("status" => 0, "info" => array("base" => $_POST["base_name"], "text" => $success."/".$total." added.")));
    }
}
```

> softwareInsertArray code:  pastebin.com/raw/vUnQTpxU

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to replace the pipes with commas?
IE SELECT replace('Thomas|Maier|5778011152|Bahnweg|232','|', ',' )

Comment: Also tried with commas. But if i leave the seperator input empty and add 5 lines in textarea infos added, but without infos, maybe because there are more DB columns not just : Name, Surname, Phone, Street,Number ?

Comment: The above solution would just return a string like this: 'Thomas, Maier, 5778011152, Bahnweg, 232' If each of these are to be treated as separate values that each correspond to another column we'll need to craft it a bit differently. Do you need to seperate each piece of your string and format an insert query to store each piece in a particular column? IE: 'Thomas' = [FirstName] 'Maier' = [LastName] etc?